# search a specified word in many word document files

Tags: c#, full-text-search, search-engine

I have many word and excel files that I want to search a specifies word(that user give it as a parameter to my app) in the content of these files. so how can I do it? I want to do this work with C#, can I do?

**my files content are in Farsi language.**

in fact I want to make a search engine with these files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look to Lucene engine or implement yourslef [Inveted Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)

Example from [lucene in 5 min](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) (changed only to 'PersianAnalyzer')

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new PersianAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_40, analyzer);

IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
addDoc(w, "Lucene in Action", "193398817");
addDoc(w, "Lucene for Dummies", "55320055Z");
addDoc(w, "Managing Gigabytes", "55063554A");
addDoc(w, "The Art of Computer Science", "9900333X");
w.close()
```

Comment: Came here to say Lucene. Lucene makes this super easy. Dump all your documents into the index and Lucene will do the hard work

Comment: Lucene support Farsi text? could you give me a simple example? Thanks